# How can I check if the speed value have been changed in the Update and then set the new speed value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the top of script:

```
public float constantSpeed;
private float lastSpeed;
```

In `Update()` if I changed `constantSpeed` in the Inspector while the game is running I want to make the change in real time in `Update()`:

```
private void Update()
{

}
```

This is how I set the speed:

```
for (int i = 0; i < instancesToMove.Length; i++)
{
    movementSpeeds[i] = constantSpeed;
}
```

But I need to make it in `Update()`. `lastSpeed` should be helper float to check if there was a change in `constantSpeed` and if there was a change modify `movementSpeeds`. But how do I check if there was a change ?

Comment: `if (lastSpeed != constantSpeed)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure `lastSpeed` gets set to the initial value of `constantSpeed`, this is probably best done in `Start()`

```
void Start() {
    lastSpeed = constantSpeed;
}
```

Then in `Update()`, you can easily check if `constantSpeed` has changed:

```
void Update() {
    if (lastSpeed != constantSpeed) {
        lastSpeed = constantSpeed;

        for (int i = 0; i < instancesToMove.Length; i++) {
            movementSpeeds[i] = constantSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good but don't compare floats like this in Unity

Comment: Good point, I definitely wouldn't compare two floats for equality, but is it considered bad practice to check for inequality when one of the purposes for the check is to then set them equal to each other?  Just bad practice in general I guess.  Use `Mathf.Approximately() `

Comment: I think it doesn't matter if `!=` or `==` is used. It fails sometimes and can introduce hard-to-find-and-fix bug. So `Mathf.Approximately` is the proper way.